# "TF14083: The item {0} has a pending merge from the current merge operation" when merging TFS2008

Tags: merge

I am getting this error when trying to merge TFS2008. There are no pending changes on either source or destination branches.

> TF14083: The item {0} has a pending merge from the current merge operation, please resolve and check in the current merge and merge again to pick up this change.

Comment: There might be some workspaces that have pending changes/merge conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/57be1299-72fc-49df-91eb-a5dfc3824e3a)?

One of the suggestions there is to try the operation in a new workspace.

Also, if you have renamed or deleted one or more branches/folders, there might be changes in your workspace you're not aware of. Is there anything (even outside the source and target) in your Pending Changes window?

Answer (score 4):

There is a "Resolve Conflicts(x)" link at the top of the pending changes window that I missed.

Comment: This fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Here's a work-around worked for me.

Short version: Merge all files that don't report TF14083 first and check in changes, then perform a remerge.

Long version:
We had no files in shelves or not checked in, but when trying to perform a merge from one branch to another I got the error message *TF14083: The item '' has a pending merge from the current merge operation, please resolve and check in the current merge and merge again to pick up this change.*

My workaround was to merge all other files except those reported with a TF14083 error. Check in that merge, then perform a new merge from and to the same branches as previously, and now TFS picked up the changes in those files reported with TF14083 in the previous merge operation and merged them with no warnings or errors.

Go figure!